# Display DriveInfo to textbox

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to display All drive info to multiline textbox3. How do i go about this?

Code i have is this

Edited:  Moved the GetDrives() out of Private void into public form1 using the new below code. But all im getting now is just one share drive to show up in textbox3  which is S:\
I also have two more network drives M:\ and J:\  why isnt it listing it all?

```
     public Form()
     {
        InitializeComponent();

        DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
        {
            if (d.IsReady && d.DriveType == DriveType.Network)
            {
                textbox3.text = d.Name;

            }
        }
      }




    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
```

Comment: You should edit your question to make it clearer what textBox3 is.  Something like `textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text + "\n" + allDrives.Name` may be a start.

Comment: your function is going to be indirectly recursive.

Comment: that actually  Did it.  Replaced `textbox3.text = d.name;` with `textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text + "\n" + d.Name;`

Comment: Yes, because of the order you're doing things. Are you using Visual Studio? Google how to use the VS debugger so you can step through the code line by line and understand what it's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to assign a string to a DriveInfo array. That just won't work. Hopefully this will get you started....

```
public Form()
{

    DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
    {
        if (d.IsReady && d.DriveType == DriveType.Network)
        {
            textBox3.Text+= String.Format("{0} Drive {1} is ready and a network drive", Environment.NewLine, d.VolumeLabel);

        }
    }
}
```